# Provision Azure RM environment from TFS for a powershell task

Tags: powershell, azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

How to set up access to Azure subscription to provision resources there with an azure resource template (Web App, Sql Server, etc.) from Visual Studio Online (TFS)? This should grant an agent running a release definition on TFS an access. Now it breaks at `Get-AzureRmContext` with that it demands to call `Login-AzureRmAccount`. But that should be automated deployment without pop up login windows. With "Azure App Service Deploy" task in TFS we have ability to connect an Azure subscription (not possible for Powershell task). Should some Azure Government be set up? Should TFS Agent be somehow given access to Azure Subscription?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [ARM template deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/cd/azure/deploy-provision-azure-vm?view=vsts) that you can use from your release definition to create or update a resource group.

One of the inputs to the task is a [Service Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts). By setting up a service endpoint, it handles all of the work of authenticating and selecting the correct subscription for you -- all you need to do is point the task at the Service Endpoint and your ARM template and it takes care of the rest.

Comment: The question about Powershell script. How to do it there?

Comment: Same answer, except use the `Azure PowerShell` task.

Comment: Yes, that should work! Thank you. I was reading about singing in with PS at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azurermps-6.3.0 actually. Creating principals, etc. But that task should do the auth. If you update your answer I will vote it as a solution.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-ci-in-vsts#set-up-continuous-deployment-in-vs-team-services shows the 2 ways - it shows VS projects but the concepts for the deployment step are the same regardless